# Consulta mysql sobre una plataforma moodle

Tags: mysql, select, sql, moodle

Estoy trabajando en crear una consulta MYSQL en una BD de moodle (v2.9 aunque posteriormente daré el salto a la v3.5) en la que figuren los siguientes datos:

- Nombre de usuario
- Nombre del alumno (solo estudiantes)
- Apellidos y nombre del alumno
- Tiempo de conexion al curso
- Nombre del curso
- Nombre del grupo al que pertenece en dicho curso
- Porcentaje de progreso en el curso

Hasta la fecha tengo esto pero tengo bastantes problemas para sacar todos los datos que necesito:

```
    SELECT     
        mdl_block_custom_reports_times.dedicationtime,    
        mdl_user.firstname,    
        mdl_user.lastname,    
        mdl_user.username,
        mdl_user.id,    
        mdl_course.fullname,  
    FROM  mdl_block_custom_reports_times    
   INNER JOIN mdl_user ON MIBD.mdl_user.id = MIBD.mdl_block_custom_reports_times.userid    
   INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_course.id = MIBD.mdl_block_custom_reports_times.course
   WHERE MIBD.mdl_user.id IN (    
            SELECT mdl_role_assignments.userid     
              FROM mdl_role_assignments    
             WHERE mdl_role_assignments.roleid = 5     
               AND mdl_role_assignments.contextid IN (SELECT mdl_context.id     
                                                        FROM mdl_context    
                                                       WHERE mdl_context.contextlevel = 50)     
                                                    ) 
            )
```

Estoy haciendo la consulta a través de MYSQL workbench y mi intencion posterior es usar esta consulta para rellenar un excel, por lo que el uso de modulos en bi es una opcion.

En cuanto a la estructura de la base de datos , [tengo este archivo MWB en el que se puede ver como es](http://www.examulator.com/er/2.9/moodle29_erd.mwb)

Comment: Bienvenido el_profesional, deberías pasarte por el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer como funciona SO. Revisa en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder obtener buenas respuestas. Deberías indicar que versión de Moodle estas usando.

Comment: Bienvenido. Es imposible ayudarte si describes el problema de una forma tan genérica. Al decir: *tengo bastantes problemas para sacar todos los datos que necesito* o *La consulta me está dando bastante la tabarra*  o ***no encuentro la tabla** que consultar para sacar dicha información* no concretizas nada. Imagínate, si no encuentras la tabla, si no conoces cómo tienes el diseño de datos ¿qué podremos decirte nosotros? Si puedes identifica el problema, dinos qué errores tienes, que datos recibes, que datos esperas recibir, pon ejemplos, no sé... Sin aterrizar el asunto veo difícil ayudarte.

Comment: El término *porcentaje del Curso* puede ser un poco ambigüo en Moodle, dependerá de tus necesidades concretas así que no hay una única tabla que analizar. Puedes revisar los plugins: [Progreso de Finalización](https://docs.moodle.org/all/es/Bloque_de_Progreso_de_Finalizaci%C3%B3n) y [Barra de progreso](https://docs.moodle.org/all/es/Bloque_de_barra_de_progreso) a ver si te arrojan algo de luz o al menos afinas un poco más la pregunta.

Comment: Edite la consulta, siento no haberme explicado correctamente, si tenéis alguna sugerencia mas, para poder facilitar mas las cosas estaré encantado de leeros, un saludo